# Move all recursive files/folders to current folder in Thunar

Tags: thunar, thunar-custom-actions

Sorry if this has been answered, I couldn't find it. Lets say I have a folder for each month, and inside of each months folder, there are files and folders that go 4 or 5 levels deep.  So:

1. April -

   -Folder 1

   ```
   -files
   ```

   -Folder 2

   ```
   -Folder 2b

      -Files
   ```

   -Files in April
2. May -

   /Folder 2

   ```
   /Files
   ```

   /Files in May

and so on and so forth.  Is there a way to add a custom action in thunar so I can just pull all of the recursive files of the current folder, just the files, into the current folder I am in?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say You have this folder/file structure:

```
tree             
.
├── 1
│   ├── 4
│   │   └── file14
│   └── file1
├── 2
│   ├── 5
│   │   └── file25
│   └── file2
└── 3
    ├── 6
    │   └── file36
    └── file3
```

Then You can use `fd` command line with conjunction of `cp` to run this command (from the root folder). Note that I am using `cp` command You probably want to use `mv` instead.

```
fd -t f -x cp {} ./{/}
```

now You fill have (in the root directory):

```
1  2  3  file1  file14  file2  file25  file3  file36
```

`fd` can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

Explanation of options (from `man fd`):

```
-t f find only files
-x   executes a command
     {}   path (of all search results
     {/}  basename
```

Now the last part is to create a script form this command and add it to thunar actions use [Custom Actions Window](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

fdfind -x cp {} ./{/}

but that definitely worked.

Is there a way to then delete the emptied folders?

Comment: Use `fd -t e -t d`. This mean "find type empty + type directory", check `man fd` for more information and combine it with `rmdir` command.